# Arguments Object is Empty Despite Setting Default Argument Value – is there a Workaround?

Tags: javascript, arguments

Given this function (e.g. in node.js)

```
> function f (a = 1) { return arguments; }
undefined
> f(1)
[Arguments] { '0': 1 } // arguments object contains value for argument a
> f()                  // invoke function f without argument
[Arguments] {}         // arguments object is empty despite default value
```

I need to be able to obtain default values if no argument is given.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: `arguments` contains the actual given arguments. Variables defined as parameters will get the default values if needed, it won’t change the `arguments` object.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. Hence my question if there might exist a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the docs:
[`arguments is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

This means that `arguments` will only hold the values that are **actually** passed to the function when a call is made.

Comment: Therefor I was asking for a workaround in my question.